# What does the `socket` declaration do in the database.yml file of a rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have downloaded a database to my desktop (I am using OSX)

I need to create rails app that uses this database, I am sorry if this question is so simple I am new to rails! I think that this `socket:` is the path to the database, is this correct?

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ttlem_demo_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I propose the answer given is correct to the question you mainly asked — even though you were looking for broader help about how to setup your configs.  Hopefully you solved that, those years ago, and can accept the given answer for "what is a socket in the database.yml"

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to be correct. If you want to connect on localhost, you'll need to add this line

```
hostname: 127.0.0.1
```

to your file.

Note that the database.yml you provide contains only a section for development. You can add other section like 'test' or 'production'. You can see an [example here](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978).

I also found a good explanation of a socket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609622/what-is-the-socket-declaration-for-in-ruby-on-rails-database-yml). Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry my question is maybe not clear, I understand how to make app with mysql but i dont understand how to use already existing database do you know how to do this?

Comment: i didnt get any errors I think have to edit the socket: in the database.yml but not so sure what that does

Comment: will adding hostname:127.0.0.1 find the existing database on my desktop with all the tables and info i want to use?

Comment: hostname:127.0.0.1 means that you work on localhost and the database server (mysql in your case) is on your computer. This is useful specially when you are testing application on development. If your database (mysql) is well installed and the connection is working, you'll be able to get info from your tables with queries.

Comment: In my Rails 4 app, the `socket` settings seems to be ignored. Instead I had to set `host: /path/to/socket/` in order for at least `rake db:migrate` to work.