# CircleCI config issue with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci

I am using CircleCI to build my Ruby on Rails application.

While building the application I am getting the error as

```
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through
socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

**config.yml**

```html
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    parallelism: 3
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.2-stretch
        environment:
          BUNDLE_JOBS: 3
          BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
          BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: circleci-demo-ruby
          RAILS_ENV: test
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
          MYSQL_DB: rails_chat_tutorial
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
          MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin --innodb-large-prefix=true --innodb-file-format=Barracuda
        environment:
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: sudo apt-get install mysql-client
     
      
      # Which version of bundler?
      - run:
          name: Which bundler?
          command: bundle -v

      # Restore bundle cache
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - rails-demo-bundle-v2-

      - run:
          name: Bundle Install
          command: bundle check || bundle install

      # Store bundle cache
      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      - run:
          name: Wait for DB
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:3306 -timeout 1m

      - run:
          name: Mysql database
          command: mysql  -h 127.0.0.1 -u root  -e "create database rails_chat_tutorial;"    

      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: bin/rails db:migrate
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: root
password: 

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_chat_tutorial
```

Comment: I notice that most environment variables are being set for your build container, but there are hardly any being set for your database container. For example, how can the database container know that you want an empty password?

Comment: Also, I would drop the MySQL `command` to start with, in case that is upsetting it. Get it working with an ordinary default database to start with, then do custom tweaking afterwards.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I sure haven't

Comment: I changed to postgres

Answer (score 2):

According to this [What is Socket Declaration in RoR for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609622/what-is-the-socket-declaration-for-in-ruby-on-rails-database-yml) It seems there are 2 ways to connect to the DB, one is via sockets and another is via TCP/IP. Sockets work fine when everything is on one computer-local machine. Since CircleCI is using different images for Ruby and Mysql, use TCP connection instead.

I had to change the `database.yml` as follows:

**database.yml**

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
```

Then CircleCI config:

**circleci/config.yml**

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.4
        environment:
          DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      - image: circleci/mysql:8.0.4
        command: [--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password]
        environment:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: app_test
          MYSQL_USER: root
```

I hope this works for you